# How to set other table Order by on ID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which images given below.

> tb_user

[image: enter user table]

> tb_user_connection

[image]

```
select * from tb_user_connection WHERE connection_type='a' 
AND user_id = '1' AND user_id <= connection_id
union all
select *
from tb_user_connection t
where user_id > connection_id 
and connection_type='a' and not exists (
select 1
from tb_user_connection t1
where t1.user_id = t.connection_id
and t1.connection_id = t.user_id 
)
```

> so, i want to get records from tb_user_connection but order by
>   tb_user.first_name so, how i can set this query?

Comment: The `connection_type` field is missing from your screen capture, and it isn't clear what your logic is.

Comment: yes @TimBiegeleisen i will take it now

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
    (select *,(select first_name fron tb_user where tb_user.id =tb_user_connection.user_id) as first_name_my from tb_user_connection WHERE connection_type='a' 
AND user_id = '1' AND user_id <= connection_id
union all
select *,(select first_name fron tb_user where tb_user.id=t.user_id) as first_name_my
from tb_user_connection t
where user_id > connection_id 
and connection_type='a' and not exists (
select 1
from tb_user_connection t1
where t1.user_id = t.connection_id
and t1.connection_id = t.user_id 
)) dum
ORDER   BY first_name_my
```

try with this query .

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tbl_user where tbl_user.id=tb_user_connection.user_id) as first_name_my from tb_' at line 3

Comment: Wait let me check... i think sub query must be change according to your approch.

Comment: Dear i have used tbl_user . please change it and use your table_name tb_user .. Please again retry with my updated sql query.

Comment: I change with according to my approach then gives me Unknown column 'tb_user_connection.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Try again with my updated sql query . Finally it may be working.

Comment: Sorry dear but i didn't understand this query check this line (select *,(select first_name fron tb_user where tb_user.id =tb_user_connection.user_id) as first_name_my from tb_user_connection in this statement you set tb_user id = tb_user connection.user_id and after give table name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132253/discussion-between-kumar-rakesh-and-bhavin-sasapra).